# How to make a RHEL repo static for a specific release

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rpm

I have been working with CentOS for quite a while now and i got used to the way the repos are managed. Recently a new proprietary app required the company to get RHEL licences and the repo management has become a nightmare.

Synchronizing the RHEL repo means downloading almost 15k packages (for v5) and i would really like to limit my mirror to offer packages based on a specific release (i.e. 5.8, 5.9).

I have been googling for a few days and i can't find anything related. any ideas how is it implemented in CentOS?

I forgot to add that i'm already using mrepo for repo sync and cobbler for systems provisioning.

Comment: Just use those specific channels? You _do_ have Red Hat Satellite, don't you? I wouldn't even think of deploying more than a tiny handful of RHEL machines without it.

Comment: The only channel available in RHEL satellite is for the major release, they do not have child channels for each point release. if they had, i would not be asking.

Answer (score 1):

With redhat satellite you can create channels with a specific version or at a point in time with the command :

`spacewalk-create-channel --user=satadmin --server=localhost --version=5 --update=u8 --release=Server --arch=x86_64 --destChannel=rhel-5.8-x86_64 --clone`

It is important to put the --clone option to create the repo with groups.

You have another command if you want to make a repo at a point in time.

Exemple:

`spacewalk-clone-by-date --user=username --server=localhost -l rhel-x86_64-server-5 rhel-x86_64-server-5U2 -d 2012-01-19`

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Boogy, i am already using other cobbler, which conflicts with spacewalk. since i'm also using mrepo, i rather use another method... do you know the internals of the clone command? what exactly does it do?

Comment: Here is a brief explication that Red Hat gives for the command:

Script to clone software channels and errata up to specific dates ensuring any added packages have their dependencies satisfied. Any destination channels that do not exist will be created.